# Communicating both ways between classes

Tags: c#, .net

A little background on my project:
I'm making a multi-form application, which consists of 1 mainform, and 6 childforms that can be called from the mainform, but only 1 childform can be active at a time. These childforms share certain parts of code, which I do not want to copy. To solve this, I have a codefile within the same namespace which holds the nessaccary code.
This codefile however, needs access to certain properties of the currently active childform.
My search has come down to using an interface to extract the needed information from the active childform.

My code is currently looking like this:

**Interface:**

```
public interface Interface1
{
    TabControl tabControl_Buizen_
    {
        get; 
    }
    TabPage tabPage_plus_
    {
        get; 
    }
}
```

**Childform:**

```
public partial class Childform : Form, Interface1
{
    Interface1 dummy;
    public TabControl tabControl_Buizen_
    {
        get { return this.tabControl_Buizen; }
    }
    public TabPage tabPage_plus_
    {
        get { return this.tabPage_plus; }
    }
    Methods_newTabPage methods = new Methods_newTabPage(dummy);
}
```

**Codefile:**

```
public class Methods_newTabPage
{
    private readonly Interface1 form;
    public Methods_newTabPage(Interface1 formInterface)
    {
        this.form = formInterface;
    } 
}
```

As you can see I'm using `Methods_newTabPage methods = new Methods_newTabPage(dummy);` to be able to call methods in my codefile, but the codefile requires the interface to be passed (which I filled as "dummy"). This however pops the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property Childform.dummy".

How can I let the childforms access the methods in the codefile, while also giving the codefile access to certain controls in differing childforms?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve, but I think you might need the MVC-designpattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: @Natrium for windows applications [Model–view–view-model (MVVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) is more approprate

Comment: Destructive approaches apart (mvc or mvvm probably force you to rewrite your whole program, and probably not in winforms); you can try to define a base form/control class inside which you create the common methods. Then you make of all the childs inherit from that base form.

Comment: It boils down to having a codefile which can access controls of multiple forms, while these forms can call the methods inside the codefile.

Comment: If I'm understanding your logic, move the initialization of `methods` (`methods = new Methods_newTabPage(dummy);` to the form's constructor and pass `this` instead of `dummy`.

Comment: @sam While I think your approach would functionally work, would putting lots of code into a base form (mainform in my case as described above?) be considered "bad coding"? I'm quite new and want to programm efficiently if possible

Comment: @KevinL., I suggest you stick with your solution and don't have a base/main form from which your `Childform`s inherit. What you did is called _composition_ and is nowadays [favored over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: @sam No it is not bad coding, also you can define common user interface if children share something visually similar. More code reuse. I have to admit this approach is widely overlooked but has worked great for me back in the days. Seems like people tend to forget Forms are clases too :)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride but this scenario do not fit well for composition. Don't use a tool just because you have it, use the right tool.

Comment: @sam, how exactly does composition not fit well here?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride you soon experience design nightmares if you try constructor injection with winforms. (forms and VS IDE seem to work better with parameterless construtors). More on the theory OP does not have multiple way of doing his things, his system do not need to be configurated or its behavior to be changed. He does not have multiple way of providing a service he needs to optionally plug in. He just need to solve a technical issue. I'd choose my solution, i stiil may be wrong partially or totally.

Comment: @sam, I'll keep your solution in mind in case I encounter any problems with GoodNightNerdPride's. I'll stay with that one for now though, as it is the easier fix for the code I have in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is easy to fix: just make `dummy` static.

```
static Interface1 dummy;
```

However, I don't think that will help you much. Why are you passing this `dummy` to `Methods_newTabPage` anyway? This will lead to `NullReferenceExceptions` inside the code file because `dummy` was never initialized with anything.

Don't you rather want to pass `this`, i.e. the current instance of `Childform`?

But you cannot just exchange `dummy` with `this` like so:

```
// Compiler error "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context".
Methods_newTabPage methods = new Methods_newTabPage(this);
```

Instead you have to add a constructor that creates `Methods_newTabPage`:

```
public partial class Childform : Form, Interface1
{
    private Methods_newTabPage methods;

    public Childform()
    {
        methods = new Methods_newTabPage(this);
    }

    public TabControl tabControl_Buizen_ { get { return this.tabControl_Buizen; } }

    public TabPage tabPage_plus_ { get { return this.tabPage_plus; } }
}
```

Comment: I've made this change and added it to another of my childforms, and it seems to be the exact solution I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a constructor that initializes the field `methods`.

Also I don't see how that dummy makes sense. Instead initialize methods via `methods = new Methods_newTabPage(this);` in the constructor.